# memory leak issue

Tags: iphone, memory-management

am getting memory leak in the following code..pls help me to solve this..

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    //iPad specific code.
    universalApp=1;
    NSLog(@"ipad started.......");
    // Override point for customization after application launch
    window.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1004);
    //window.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,320,460);

    mainPageController = [[MainPageController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainPageController" bundle:nil];
    //  [mainPageController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460)];

    [window addSubview:mainPageController.view];//memory leak

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: How are you measuring the memory leaks? Have you tried build and analyse? Or are you using the leaks tool?

Comment: You shouldn't be so worried by a leak of the app main view in the main (and only) window. It will be released when the app exit, don't worry ;-)

Comment: the leaks tool always leaks at that point - I think its a bug. I've always learnt to use build and analyse rather than the leaks tool.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a leak there, assuming you're releasing `mainPageController` in `-applicationWillTerminate:` or your app delegate's `-dealloc`. What's the problem?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply...no i didnt release in dealloc or in applicationWillTerminate.

Answer (score 0):

You should release *mainPageController* if you dont release it  in *-applicationWillTerminate:* or your app delegate's *-dealloc* like **Noah Witherspoon** says.

So, you should modify the code like this if you aren't using ARC:

```
mainPageController = [[[MainPageController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainPageController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

or

```
[window addSubview:mainPageController.view];//memory leak
[mainPageController release];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

And of course, you should read the [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1)